# Why am I getting "Enter Parameter Value"?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to list all publishers with one book on the database.

Query:

```
SELECT Publisher
FROM book
GROUP BY Publisher
HAVING COUNT(book) = 1;
```

Comment: Fixed it, it should be COUNT(Publisher) not COUNT(book).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the problem is here ...

```sql
HAVING COUNT(book) = 1
```

The table is named `book`.  Unless that table also includes a field named `book`, Access will be confused.

If you want to see `Publisher` which have only one row, use this ...

```sql
SELECT Publisher
FROM book
GROUP BY Publisher
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```